# JQuery callback not executed?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to have a progressbar that take data from server, so I created 2 servlets the first one (`process`) starts the process and when it ends return the result; the second one (`GetEvent`) gets progress information from session every 500ms..

All of this works normally and the progress information is displayed correctly, but the 
process Servlet's callback never executes.

```
 <html>
    <head>
      <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

      <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
      process();
     $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 0 });
         $("#progressStatus").html("");

        getEvent();
      });
      function process()
      {
       $.getJSON("process", function(result){
         //never executed
         alert( "Result: " );

       });
      }
      function getEvent()
      {
        $.getJSON("GetProgressEvent", function(data) {     
        $.each(data.ProgressEvents, function(){
        $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: this.progress });
         $("#progressStatus").html(this.status);
        });
        });
           setTimeout(getEvent, 500);
      }
      </script>
    </head>
    <body style="font-size:62.5%;">

    <div id="progressbar"></div>
    <div id ="progressStatus"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I just started with JQuery and I don't know what's wrong with this code.

Comment: Are you sure the GetProgressEvent call is actually returning?  Have you inspected the HTTP traffic using a web browser inspector such as the Net panel in Chrome or FireFox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are calling $.getJSON with a url "process" 
this function has no error handling if there is problem with the response or invalid JSON is returned then the callback will not be called.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

jQuery.getJSON( url, [data], [success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] )

url A string containing the URL to which the request is sent.

data A map or string that is sent to the server with the request.

success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)A callback function that is executed if the request succeeds.

Try adding a valid url in place of "process" and if that fails use the 
$.ajax method as follows

```
$.ajax({
  url: "mydomain.com/url",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  data: $.param( $("Element or Expression") ),

  complete: function() {
    //called when complete
  },

  success: function() {
    //called when successful
 },

  error: function() {
    //called when there is an error
  },
});
```

Comment: exactly, the JSON returned from servlet was invalid :(